# Netty app hangs when I try to close a io.netty.channel.Channel using closeFuture()

Tags: java, netty

My Netty app hangs when I try to close a io.netty.channel.Channel TCP/IP client connection.

I do:

```
ch.isOpen(); //this is TRUE
ch.closeFuture().sync(); //never returns
```

stack trace for the thread calling sync is here.

```
JavaFX Application Thread@583, prio=5, in group 'main', status: 'WAIT'
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.await(DefaultPromise.java:260)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.await(DefaultChannelPromise.java:129)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.await(DefaultChannelPromise.java:28)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.sync(DefaultPromise.java:224)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.sync(DefaultChannelPromise.java:117)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.sync(DefaultChannelPromise.java:28)
at MyClient.stop(MyClient.java:46)
```

Is there something that can prevent a channel from closing?  Can I force it closed another way?

Comment: `Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
 b.bind(port).sync().channel().closeFuture().await();`

Usually you bind a channel to the bootstrap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

closeFuture.sync() is not for closing the Channel but rather allows you to block until the Channel is closed. For closing the Channel you would call Channel.close().

Comment: quite right! I thought I had tried close() also but apparently not because it works as advertised.  Thanks a lot.